# Why are my Angular Material form elements not displayed in the view?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on a small **Recipes** application in Angular 9.

In `src/app/recipe-form/recipe-form.component.ts` I have

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {MatSelect} from "@angular/material/select";

@Component({
  selector: 'recipe-form',
  templateUrl: './recipe-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-form.component.scss']
})
export class RecipeFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

In recipe-form.component.html I have:

```
<form #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput name="name" value="">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
      <input matInput name="description" value="">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Matching Drink</mat-label>
        <mat-select>
           <mat-option *ngFor="let drink of drink" [value]="drink.value">{{drink.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-label>Recipe</mat-label>
      <textarea name="full_description"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div>
         <button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid" class="btn btn-lg btn-block">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>

    <button mat-button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid" class="btn btn-lg btn-block">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

For some reason I was unable to figure out the only form elements displayed in the view are the textarea and the submit button.

What is missing?

---

## UPDATE:

The text fields (`input type="text"`) are visible now but there is no underline, despite using `appearance="outline"`:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Description" required>
</mat-form-field>
```

Also there is this error in the console: `Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl`.

Comment: have you imported MatInputModule and MatFormFieldModule in the module where you have your recipe component declared ?

Comment: In the textarea can you please add "matInput"?
I think it should work becasue I have tried your html code to the stackblitz. you can try over here https://stackblitz.com/angular/jeedeqmjevy?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.html

Comment: @saumil_jariwala You are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have imported your material module inside your recipe module. if however recipe component is declared within appModule then you have to import mat module there !!

Also please check for FormsModule, as you are using mat-form-field. Your appmodule should import it before you import material module.

e.g

```
   @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RecipeFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and material module something like this

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        MatCardModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatIconModule,
        DragDropModule
    ],
    exports: [
        MatCardModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatIconModule,
        DragDropModule
    ],
    providers: []
}
)
export class MaterialModule {

}
```

**Update**:

based on your error your mat input field should contain matInput directive. For more information have a look here at [sample and documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples)

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: It is imported "globally" in the module the component belongs to, this way: `import {MaterialLibraryModule} from '../../core/material-library.module';`.

Comment: is it also there in the  imports: section ?

Comment: Yes.  `imports: [
        MaterialLibraryModule,
        AnotherModule
    ]`

Comment: can you please post errors from ur debug console ? also did you check if you have FormsModule imported ? Since you are using mat-form-field, FormsModule should be imported as well

Comment: In the VS code console there are no errors. In the browser console I get `ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.`.

Comment: check here for this issue !! https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9411

Comment: The text fields (`input type="text"`) are visible now but there is no underline, despite using `appearance="outline"`: `<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
   <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Description" required>
      </mat-form-field>`. Also tehre is this error in the console: `Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl`.

Comment: did you try the solution given at the end of the github link ?

Comment: This **[one](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9411#issuecomment-616489880)**, at the very end?

Comment: My form component is in a shared module. Should it have its own module?